# concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'join_axes' using ProfileReport

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I use VS Code for codding. I got error using ProfileReport in code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 5), columns=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
```

```
profile = ProfileReport(df)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
e:\DS\Yandex_Practikum\Projects\trying.ipynb Ячейка 3 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 profile = ProfileReport(df)

File e:\Program Files (x86)\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\__init__.py:66, in ProfileReport.__init__(self, df, **kwargs)
     62 """Constructor see class documentation
     63 """
     64 sample = kwargs.get('sample', df.head())
---> 66 description_set = describe(df, **kwargs)
     68 self.html = to_html(sample,
     69                     description_set)
     71 self.description_set = description_set

File e:\Program Files (x86)\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\describe.py:392, in describe(df, bins, check_correlation, correlation_threshold, correlation_overrides, check_recoded, pool_size, **kwargs)
    390         if name not in names:
    391             names.append(name)
--> 392 variable_stats = pd.concat(ldesc, join_axes=pd.Index([names]), axis=1)
    393 variable_stats.columns.names = df.columns.names
    395 # General statistics

File e:\Program Files (x86)\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:311, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    305 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    306     warnings.warn(
    307         msg.format(arguments=arguments),
...
    309         stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310     )
--> 311 return func(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'join_axes'
```

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the problem according to what was posted on github:

> This issue happens when, for instance, a report is converted to an iframe via in a notebook environment (Google Colab, Jupyter Lab, Jupyter Notebook, etc). This is due to an incompatibility in an old package version (particularly 1.4.1, which a installation may default to, as discussed above). Upgrading the package to a newer version (either via or fixes the issue. **conda pip install pandas-profiling==3.2.0 - conda install -c conda-forge pandas-profiling=3.2.0**

visit the [module's github page](https://github.com/ydataai/pandas-profiling/blob/bfe9139c1f81d87e03430d41cffe1fca27c8d0c3/docsrc/source/pages/support_contrib/common_issues.rst)  for more information.